# Contacts keep crashing

Tags: android

**Contacts keep crashing**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Uri allContacts= Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
    Cursor c=managedQuery(allContacts,null,null,null,null);

    String[] columns=new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};
    int[] views=new int[]{R.id.ContactsName,R.id.ContactsID};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adaptor=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main,c,columns,views);
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    listView.setAdapter(adaptor);
```

"Tried running ,, it is showing contacts keep crashing in Naugat Android 7"

I am new to Android ..
thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to ask permission for reading contact at runtime. read more https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: please add the crash logcat although the comment above me is correct

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml file between the `<manifest>` tags:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: since Androi Marshmallow this won't be enough. You will also need to request the persmissions at Runtime!

Comment: I have given permission.